# Input box will be covered by the soft keyboard

Tags: android

A navigation bar at the bottom of the page. The`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`, Click on the input box in a `webview`, the navigation bar is at the bottom of the top up. if the `android:windowSoftInputMode = "adjustPan"`.Click on the input box in a `webview`,the Input box will be covered by the soft keyboard, display not to come out. 
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Try a ScrollView around your layout.

Comment: I have tried, no effect